# Python 3.12.1でのTPOT 0.12.1の読み込みエラーについて

Tags: python, 機械学習

Python3.12.1でAutoMLのTPOTを利用しようと考えています。
ターミナルでtpotをインストール後、

```
from tpot import TPOTClassifier
```

でtpotをインポートしたところ以下のエラーが発生しました。

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imp'

調べた限り、impはPython3.8以降サポートされていないようですが、
TPOTを利用するためにはPythonのバージョンを下げるしかないでしょうか？
OSはWindowsです。

Comment: 2ヶ月程前に Issue として報告されています。[In python 3.12, Get error after importing module. · Issue #1327 · EpistasisLab/tpot](https://github.com/EpistasisLab/tpot/issues/1327) 開発側のアクションはなく、報告者は "I fixed this by manually erasing "import imp" in base.py of tpot." としたそうです。

Comment: 解決することが出来ました。
情報提供ありがとうございました。